# Angular2 recursive component output

Tags: recursion, angular, tree

I have following problem:
let's assume that I have `Component A` that have two `subcomponents Ar` and `Ad`. `Subcomponent Ar` is recursive created tree and `subcomponent Ad` is component which shows details about choosen node in recursive tree (`subcomponent Ar`). How can I send selected node from sub(sub)component in `Ar` to `Component Ad` using `@Output`? Should it be `@Output` or something else?

**app.component.html:**

```
<tree [input]="fooTree" [output]="updateDetails($event)"></tree>
<tree-details [input]="input"></tree-details>
```

**tree.component.html:**

```
<tree [input]="fooTree.children"></tree>
```

**tree-details.component.html**

```
<div>{{input.name}}</div>
<div>{{input.id}}</div>
```

In this case I will see only root tree details, how can I do this to get info from other node (one of recursivly created), when is selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Its easier to see in a demo-app: https://plnkr.co/edit/WaYluZyPaC0OEV0YovbC?p=preview

..

Your `tree-component` Ar could have an `@Ouput()`.
Your AppComponent would consume this output and would post the selected data to the second sub-component `detail-component`.

**app.component.html**

```
<tree (yourOutputNameHere)="yourFunctionToReceiveAndPostSelectedData($event)"></tree>
<details #yourDetailViewComponent></details>
```

**tree.component.html**

```
<tree (yourOutputNameHere)="yourFunctionToReceiveAndPostSelectedData($event)"></tree>
```

Your `tree-component` could even have an `@Input()` and inside of your template you could do something like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<tree [detail-view-input]="yourDetailViewComponent"></tree>
<details #yourDetailViewComponent></details>
```

**tree.component.html**

```
<tree [detail-view-input]="detailViewInput"></tree>
```

Comment: But whats with tree.component.html? there shouldnt be any output?

Comment: This is exatcly what I needed. Thank you very much :)